# What is the correct way of postgres configuration on Mac?

Tags: postgresql, macos

I want to install and use Postgres for a Rust application (web server) I am running. I used the `brew install postgresql@15` command, followed by setting the PATH variable:

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

In a new terminal, when I type `postgres`, I am unable to get it started. I get the following error:

```
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
```

What is the correct way for me to set this variable?

My intention is to have a `postgres` role with no password.

Comment: No an answer, but it works for me, just download a complete working environment: https://postgresapp.com

Comment: What is the content of pg_hba file? What happen when you issue psql -U postgres?

Comment: 1) [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-postgres.html) is the command to start the server. You should not be using it. 2) Read [Homebrew](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew) for more information. It explains how to start the server.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the output of that command is an error: `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

Comment: What command?  Read all the information at the Homebrew link, there is no `postgres` role created by the install. Instead the default user(role) is the OS username you installed Postgres as. Personally I second @FrankHeikens suggestion to use `postgresapp`, it actually has useful documentation.

Comment: Sorry, the command I executed what @jlandercy asked me to, `psql -U postgres`

Comment: That won't work as there is no `postgres` created as part of the install. Read the `Homebrew` link I posted earlier.

Comment: Perhaps better asked on the sister site dba.StackExchange.com